# Losing data consistently over sockets (but not when using localhost connections)

Tags: c++, c, sockets, buffer

I'm trying to get comfortable with socket programming. I've written a client/server game, and am seeing some strange results.

**Below is the code for the client portion:**

---

```
while(1){
        char response[100];
        memset(&buf[0], 0, sizeof(buf));
        //buf[numbytes] = '\0';
        socklen_t addr_len = sizeof their_addr;
        if ((numbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_len)) == -1) {
            perror("recv");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (strcmp(buf, "exit 99") == 0){
            close(sockfd);
            return 0;
        }

        printf("%s\n",buf);

        std::cin >> response;
        struct msgstruct message;
        message.send_data = response;
        message.length = strlen(message.send_data);
        int n   = sendto(sockfd, response, strlen(response), 0, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen);
    }
```

---

**This communicates through the "server", via the following code snippet:**

```
int StartMasterMind(int client, sockaddr_storage addr_in) 
{
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr = addr_in;
    socklen_t addr_len;
    char buf[MAXDATASIZE];
    buf[MAXDATASIZE] = '\0';

    sendMsg(client, "Welcome to ... M-A-S-T-E-R-M-I-N-D.\nThe game has begun.\n");

// [..] redacted for clarity 

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {

    sendMsg(client, "Please enter your guess: ");

    addr_len = sizeof their_addr;
    recv(client, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0/*, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_len*/);
    current_try = GetInputAsColorMap(buf);

// [..] redacted for clarity -- several for() loops below here
}



//basic message structure
struct msgstruct {
        int length;
        char* send_data;
};

//basic method for sending messages
int sendMsg(int client, char* theMsg)
{
    msgstruct message;
    message.send_data = theMsg;
    message.length = strlen(message.send_data);

    return (send(client, message.send_data, message.length, 0));
}
```

---

So, if I connect via local host:  `./client localhost <port>`, then everything appears to be ok:

```
c@ub1:~/Documents/dev$ ./client localhost 9990
client: connecting to 127.0.0.1
Welcome to ... M-A-S-T-E-R-M-I-N-D.
The game has begun.
Please enter your guess:
```

However, when connecting over the network from another VM, I consistently get:

```
c@ub1:~/Documents/dev$ ./client 192.168.1.111 9990
client: connecting to 192.168.1.111
Welcome to ... M-A-S-T-E-R-M-I-N-D.
The game has begun.
```

Notice the missing `Please enter your guess:`  - I'm a bit at a loss for what to do here. I can't figure out why/when/where this data is getting dropped. Because of this, I'm a little afraid to continue, because I just assume somewhere I have a buffer that's going to overflow and wreck everything.

Comment: Which protocol do you use? You might like to show how the socket is created?

Comment: In case you use TCP: Closely read the man-pages for recv()/send() and learn that at least for sockets those two functions do not necessarily receive/send as much bytes as they were told to, but few. So looping around such calls counting until all data or a terminator had been received/sent is a good idea, not to say an essential necessity.

Answer (score 2):

You're making all the usual mistakes. You're assuming that one send equals one receive. You're not making use of the read count returned by recv() when using he receive buffer. You're assuming that TCP is a messaging protocol. It's a byte-stream protocol.

Comment: Threee strikes and you're out.